# CSV reader offsets first two rows in a table

Tags: tables, pdftex, csvsimple

I am trying to use CSV reader (from the `csvsimple` package) to print out some data to a table. However, I am observing a weird offset in the first two cells of the first column:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data.csv}
  x,y,z
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    $x$ & $y$ & $z$
    \tabularnewline
    \hline\hline
    42  & 43  & 44  \tabularnewline\hline
    \csvreader[
      head to column names,
      late after line=\tabularnewline\hline]
    {data.csv}{}{
    \x  & \y  & \z
    }
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: offsets]

This issue clearly comes from the `\csvreader` macro (removing the first line of hardcoded data does not affect the offset); using `p{0.5cm}` instead of `l` solves the issue for me, but I would ideally want to stick with `l`. What am I missing here?

My TeX is `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.10.20)`
My `csvsimple` is `Package: csvsimple 2019/04/09 version 1.21 LaTeX CSV file processing`

UPD: ideally, I would like to retain the separation of the body of the table and the header, since this is a small piece of a bigger puzzle and I would like to be able to design a complex table header)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.csv}
  x,y,z
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
\end{filecontents*}

 \csvautotabular{test.csv}
\csvreader[
tabular = |l|l|l|,
table head = \hline $X$&$Y$ &$Z$\\\hline\hline,
late after line = \\\hline
]{test.csv}{}{%
\csvcoli&\csvcolii & \csvcoliii
}
\end{document}
```

**Edit as per OP requirement**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.csv}
  x,y,z
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
\end{filecontents*}

 \csvautotabular{test.csv}
 %
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline%
                $x$ & $y$ & $z$ \\\hline\hline
 \csvreader[
            late after line = \\\hline
            ]
            {test.csv}{}{%
 \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii
 }%
 \end{tabular}
 \end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Would it be possible to retain the markup where `\csvreader` is only tasked with filling up the body of the table (i.e. I am free to configure the header to be as complex as I need)?

Comment: an example of usage would be helpful to decide-- in case the above answer met your requirement and removed the offset please consider accepting the answer and upvoting

Comment: @BigMonday  please see the edit above ---is this what you wanted

Comment: Thank you again. Looks like its the `%` character before the newline in the last parameter to `\csvreader` that fixes the issue.

Comment: @BigMonday would you like to accept the answer

Comment: Upon scrutinizing your answer, I posted my own, clarifying the original problem and preserving the initial markup as much as possible. Thank you once again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way with `readarray`.  Make sure you use v3.1 2021-09-17.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data.csv}
  x,y,z
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
  42,43,44
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{readarray}
\def\firstrow{\hline}
\renewcommand\typesetrowsepchar{\\\firstrow\hline\gdef\firstrow{}}
\renewcommand\typesetcolsepchar{&}
\renewcommand\typesetcell[1]{$#1$}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \readarraysepchar{,}
  \readdef{data.csv}\tabdata
  \readarray*\tabdata\tabarray[-,\ncols]
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \typesetarray\tabarray
    \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you eliminate the `\hline` from the definition of `\typesetrowsepchar`, one obtains

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While [@js bibra's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619117/227304) technically solves the problem, it turns out that the extra spacing is generated due to the newline in the row declaration (i.e. the last parameter passed to `\csvreader`). Simply changing

```tex
\csvreader[
  head to column names,
  late after line=\tabularnewline\hline]
{data.csv}{}{
  \x  & \y  & \z
}
```

to

```tex
\csvreader[
  head to column names,
  late after line=\tabularnewline\hline]
{data.csv}{}{%
  \x  & \y  & \z
}
```

solves the problem without any further modifications.

[image: fix]

More info: [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat)